# Увеличение числа в строке Python

Tags: python, parse, qregularexpression

Парсил ресурс, тот что в коде. Решил форсировать поиск линков, с помощью регулярок. Так как там только цифры меняются. Да вот незадача, в названии ресурса 3 присутствует. И тройка тоже увеличилась в `range`.)

Как добавить тройку в исключение?

А то python создает несуществующие ресурсы. Конечно, можно потом  *[www.w3resource.com](http://www.w3resource.com)*, с помощью `replace`,  приписать правильный хост - но это не элегантно ). Хотелось бы регулярками ограничиться.

```
import re

for i in range(1, 88):
    s = "https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/string/python-data-type-string-exercise-1.php"
    print(re.sub('(\d+)(?!\d)', lambda x: str(int(x.group(0)) + i), s))
```

Такая шляпа, к примеру, получается:

> ```
> https://www.w4resource.com/python-exercises/string/python-data-type-string-exercise-2.php
> https://www.w5resource.com/python-exercises/string/python-data-type-string-exercise-3.php
> https://www.w6resource.com/python-exercises/string/python-data-type-string-exercise-4.php
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

тут можно обойтись без регулярок:

```
for i in range(1, 88):
    s = f"https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/string/python-data-type-string-exercise-{i}.php"
    print(s)
```

можно ссылку разделить на две части и менять только вторую:

```
for i in range(1, 88):
    s = "python-exercises/string/python-data-type-string-exercise-1.php"
    print("https://www.w3resource.com/" + re.sub('(\d+)(?!\d)', lambda x: str(int(x.group(0)) + i), s))
```

Comment: Тем не менее, кому то будет полезна и с регулярками инфа. Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: print(re.sub('(\d+)(?!\w)', lambda x: str(int(x.group(0)) + i), s)) Поменял 'd' на 'w ' в регулярке .Тоже работает. Короче, вариантов все больше.) Здесь проверил https://regex101.com/